# Implicit conversion and operator overload

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, implicit-conversion

So, I wrote something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int32_t i)
{
    cout << "int32: " << i << endl;
}

void f(int16_t i)
{
    cout << "int16: " << i << endl;
}

void f(int8_t i)
{
    cout << "int8: " << i << endl;
}

void f(uint32_t i)
{
    cout << "uint32: " << i << endl;
}

void f(uint16_t i)
{
    cout << "uint16: " << i << endl;
}


int main() {
    uint8_t i = 0u;
    f(i);
    return 0;
}
```

And it printed

```
int32: 0
```

---

I'm a bit confused:

- Is this well-defined behaviour, or is it implementation specific?
- What are the rules that determine which overload is used here and to what type the variable is converted?

Comment: It's not an answer to the question, but I think it's good to know that constrained templates can be used to disable implicit conversions. Example:

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d25bb8d892d8dc9b

(or constexpr if can be used as an alternative)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In comparing the conversions needed by different overloaded functions, a ["promotion"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions) is considered a better conversion sequence than a standard "conversion".  Every arithmetic type can promote to at most one other type.  (Promotions are also used when passing an argument to a C-style variadic function like `printf`. The unary `+` operator can be used to force a promotion of an arithmetic expression, like `+n`.)

For integer types which are not character types or `bool`, the promoted type is:

- If `int` can represent all the values of the original type, then `int`;
- Otherwise, if `unsigned int` can represent all the values of the original type, then `unsigned int`;
- Otherwise, the original type itself (promotion does nothing)

In your example, when comparing the overloaded functions, an "exact match" would be best, but there is no function taking exactly `int8_t` (or `int8_t&` or `const int8_t&`).  The promoted type of `uint8_t` is `int`, since it's required to support a range much larger than 0-255.  And apparently on your system, `int32_t` is an alias for `int`, so the function `void f(int32_t);` requires only a promotion on the argument.  The other functions are all viable, but require an integer conversion on the argument.  So `void f(int32_t);` is considered the best overload.

So the technical answer to the question is that it is implementation specific, but only because of the relationship between `int` and the `<cstdint>` types, not because of the overload resolution rules.

Answer (score 9):

The behavior is well-defined, *but* implementation-specific. With a 16-bit `int` it would have been different.

The particular rules in the standard are:

[[over.best.ics]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.best.ics) for overload resolution.
[[conv.prom]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.prom) for integral promotion.